# TypeScript - type parameter not recognized in tsx file?

Tags: typescript, generics, jsx

I have an example file called "test.ts" with this code:

```
const test = <T>(a: string) => { return a; } ;
```

It works! If I rename the file to "test.tsx" then Visual Studio Code marks the T parameter with red, and gives the following error:

```
[ts] Cannot find name 'T'.

[ts] JSX element 'T' has no corresponding close tag.
```

I must use .tsx extension because the actual code needs to return JSX elements. I also must use type parameters. But how can I do both?

Comment: Dunno, that answer cannot be accepted. I should post my own answer, and accept that. Doing it anyway... if I can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tsx and generic arrow functions don't mix well. The simplest solution is to use a regular function, since you don't capture `this` from the declaring context anyway:

```
const withLazyStatus = function<T>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<ILazyState<T>>) {
    return class WithLazyStatus extends React.Component<ILazyState<T>> {
        // Enhance component name for debugging and React-Dev-Tools
        static displayName = `withLazyStatus(${WrappedComponent.name})`;

        render() {
            let props = this.props;
            if (props.fetching) {
                return loading;
            } else if (props.error) {
                return error(props.error);
            } else {
                return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Or the other option is to add a type constraint :

```
 const withLazyStatus = <T extends object>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<ILazyState<T>>) {
        return  ...
  };
```

The constraint will disambiguate the generic vs tag constructs

Comment: Meanwhile, I figured out it myself but you posted it as an answer sooner. :-)

Comment: @nagylzs Still good for others to reference in the future :). I edited the answer after posting, and added the second option which also works well in you need arrow functions

Comment: <T extends object> is genius

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript also uses angle brackets for type assertions so JSX’s syntax introduces certain parsing difficulties.

So you can use the keyword `as` for this:

```
const test = (a: string) => { return a; } as T;
```

The as operator is available in both .ts and .tsx files, and is identical in behavior to the other type assertion style.

Comment: This does not work in my case, I'm updating the question.